# winapi declaration in c#

Tags: c#, winapi

Somebody could tell me how to declare winapi in c#?
I'm having this error:

```
Error   1   The name 'WinApi' does not exist in the current context bla bla bla...
```

in line:

```
 WinApi.OpenProcess(WinApi.PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, (uint)aProc[0]);
```

Comment: If you are wanting to add a declaration for the Win32 OpenProcess API function, you might take a look at the article [here](http://henrikfalk.wordpress.com/2009/07/21/c-openprocess/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're not using a library that provides those methods and constants, you'll need to implement them yourself using [Platform Invocation Services (P/Invoke)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

For example:

```
public static class WinApi {
    public const int PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = /* whatever the value is */;

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(int dwDesiredAccess,
        bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);
}
```